# Image encryption using AES algorithm in Java

Tags: java, image, aes

Is there a library available in java to encrypt a string?
Is there any library to encrypt and decrypt an image using AES in Java?

Comment: I haven't seen any libraries that let you encrypt strings - only byte arrays.

Comment: Okay... Any library which encrypts an image?

Comment: Any library that can encrypt byte arrays can encrypt images. Or songs. Or strings. Or anything you want.

Comment: Have you read this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/992019/2970947)?

Answer (score 1):

You can encrypt an image by piping it out to `ByteArrayOutputStream`, using `Cipher.doFinal` on the result bytes and writing that to an output source.

Example:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos);
SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance( ... );
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
output = cipher.doFinal(baos.toByteArray());
```